# Sliding Issues With Jquery

Tags: jquery, slidedown, slideup

I have had a look around but I can not seem to find any one else with the same issue as me. I want to be able to slide a box, which will hold my menu links, up and down on a users click.

My code below sort of works, as it does slide down when clicked, then slides back up when clicked again. However when you click the button a second time, it does not stay down, it just slides right back up again!

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  $('#Link').click(function() {
      $('#Box').slideDown('slow', function() {   
      $('#Link').click(function() { $('#Box').slideUp('slow')  });   });
  });
});
```

Comment: jsfiddle is often very useful with question like this :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5YkTz/ .slideToggle ??

Comment: Many Thanks cjmling the toggle works fine with no issues that I can see! And have noted that people use jsfiddle a lot, its just I am normally asking about PHP/CakePHP and not jquery, but will use it next time I post. - Just a side note, why is Toggle better than using slideup and slidedown, should I use Toggle in most cases? Is it better? Many Thanks Glenn Curtis

Answer (score 2):

Try to use toggle,

```
$('#menu_button').toggle(
    function () {
        $('#playfield').animate({ left: constantMenuWidth }, 500, function (e) {
            $('#menu_button').html('<img id="menu_button" src="images/menu_button.png" width="80" height="29" />');
        });
    },
    function () {
        $('#playfield').animate({ left: 0 }, 500, function (e) {
            $('#menu_button').html('<img id="menu_button" src="images/menu_button.png" width="80" height="29" />');
        });
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

use `.slideToggle()`

```
$('#Link').click(function() {
    $('#Box').slideToggle('slow', function()
    {
        // Animation complete.
    });
});
```